# Keep getting error from php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, uuid

I'm trying to create a website that grabs stats from a database that the minecraft server creates. I'm having trouble with the uuid being inserted into mojangs API and coming out as a username. It works when you visit the site the first time but when you refresh it im getting errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/07eb744f35b74ac083e90e0377a5a967): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 429 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 47
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 49
Warning: file_get_contents(https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/f5cf9ff1b9a74176983bb8b1d0c0ee70): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 429 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 47
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 49
```

After i refreshed it the names dissapeared out of the table and it gave me those errors. I really need a fix to this and as quickly as possible!

```
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: #3be5de;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<title>SuperBlaze27 Players-Server Stats</title>
<!--<link>-->
</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family: arial; color: #23a09b;">
<h1>SuperBlaze27 Minecraft Server Player Stats</h1>
<h3>Player joins</h3>
</div>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "stats";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "stats3";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `stats3_joins`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
echo "<table><tr><th>Uniqe Player ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Player Head</th><th>Times Joined</th></tr>

";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$uuid = $row["uuid"];
$uuid = str_replace('-', '', $uuid);
$json_response = file_get_contents("https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" . $uuid . "");
$data = json_decode($json_response);
        print "<tr><td>#" . $row["id"]. "</td><td> ". $data->name . "</td><td><img src='https://crafatar.com/avatars/" . $uuid . "?size=32'/img></td><td>" . $row["value"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
        echo "</table>";


// echo "Player name:".$data->name;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Btw the password i replaced with *** but in the real one it works so thats not the problem. Thx so much in advance!

Comment: Could you apply consistent formatting? Sites like pastebin can help.

Comment: @mateusz-sip https://pastebin.com/raw/KSm31q1T

Comment: are you sure that `$json_response = file_get_contents("https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" . $uuid . "");` returns valid response?

Comment: You treat it like a valid data source without checking its behaviour.

Comment: @mateusz-sip hmmmm what do you mean by that? how can i fix it?

Comment: and yes it does. you can see it here: http://23.112.142.15 but when you refresh it you get that error

Answer (score 0):

429 HTTP error means that you're sending too many requests in second to the server (sessionserver.mojang.com in your case).

The fact that you have to deal with a limit is quite expected, since reading from MySQL is very fast and your server makes many requests every second to get data. You need to add delays before the queries to fix this (which, in turn, can slow down the page load). Therefore, I also advise you to cache the received data and not to download it again every time the page is requested.

Comment: Okay thank you! I actually found a site that works! now im using https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/<uuid> and it works 100%!